# how to prevent sed to add a new line char

Tags: bash, shell, sed

part of my shell script and a variable

```
-d [% nameoffile %]_pathName
 foldername=BOM_details # its just a folder name containing bill of materials
```

I need to substitute [% nameoffile %] with BOM_details

I successfully tried

```
sed -i "s/\[\% nameoffile\%\]/$foldername/g" $filename
```

but the problem is it is adding new line immediately after replacing

what I got

```
-d BOM_details
_pathName
```

what I need is

```
-d BOM_details_pathName
```

Comment: What BOM are you dealing with? UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and if 16 or 32 what endianess? See: [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Please (re)read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should be able to show a short (maybe 4 lines?) shell script that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I suspect BOM = 'bill of materials' and not 'byte order mark'.

Comment: That helps. Follow up with a MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the variable `foldername` contains a newline char or carriage return at the end of the string (how did you initialise this variable?), you can remove it with the following syntax:

```
sed -i "s/\[\% nameoffile\%\]/${foldername//[$'\r\n']}/g" $filename
```